# How to convert group of objects into an Array in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I have a group of objects like this

```
         {
           'name'   :'Andrew',
           'gender' :'Male',
           'dob'    :'12/12/1991'
         },

         {
           'name'   :'Robby',
           'gender' :'Male',
           'dob'    :'12/12/1996'
         },
```

How do I convert this to an array of objects?
For example

```
myArray:Array<any>= [
          {
              'name'   :'Andrew',
              'gender' :'Male',
              'dob'    :'12/12/1991'
          },

          {
               'name'   :'Robby',
               'gender' :'Male',
               'dob'    :'12/12/1996'
          },
     ]
```

I'm expecting group of objects to be converted into Array of objects. How do I achieve this in Typescript?

Comment: the first example is not a valid struture in js..

Comment: `myObj` doesn't seem to be a valid object

Comment: The first snippet of yours isn't a valid js code. You must have key to value, and you have only values...

Comment: @yarons I'm getting data from backed as objects in the form of { }. I want to put these in an array.

Comment: @NitzanTomer I'm getting data from the backed as group of objects. I want to put all these in an array

Answer (score 3):

The data that you're getting, if it's a valid json should look like this:

```
"key1": {
    'name'   :'Andrew',
    'gender' :'Male',
    'dob'    :'12/12/1991'
},
"key2": {
    'name'   :'Robby',
    'gender' :'Male',
    'dob'    :'12/12/1996'
}
...
```

If you have that in a variable then:

```
let json = that json strucutre
let objs = Object.keys(json).map(key => json[key]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches, but a basic viable option is to use a for-in loop to populate an array, like so:

`myArray = []
for (anObject in myObjects) { 
   myArray.push(anObject)
}`

Comment: This will fetch only keys, not both keys and values

Comment: It is an array of objects. If you need to display the keys then use Object.keys.